# What is the difference between "sign" and "symbol"?

Tags: word-choice, nouns

For example:

> 1. A piece of meat with hair on it was a symbol of important events such as declaring war, a victorious army's return, or sad news.
> 2. A piece of meat with hair on it was a sign of important events such as declaring war, a victorious army's return, or sad news.

For example:

> 3. In some places, the bridegroom plants some banana trees and sugar canes in front of his house, the banana trees a wish for the prosperity of later generations, and the sugar canes a sweet sign of a happy life.
> 4. In some places, the bridegroom plants some banana trees and sugar canes in front of his house, the banana trees a wish for the prosperity of later generations, and the sugar canes a sweet symbol of a happy life.

example 1 and 3 are what I read in an article (a Chinese-English translation).

I looked up in a dictionary and found that sometimes "sign" means "indication" but I am still confused.

Are example 2 and 4 correct?

Comment: The main difference is that a sign *may* presage an event, while a symbol never does.  In general, *sign* has a broader range of meanings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a broad overlap between sign and symbol; it's a nuanced distinction.

In your examples, *sign* should be read as a synonym for *evidence*. More broadly, there is an intrinsic link between the sign and what it signifies. On the other hand, a *symbol* is merely a declaration that has an imposed relationship with what it declares.

For example, one might say that *a smile is a sign of contentment* if it is accepted that contented people tend to smile. One could also say that *a smile is a symbol of contentment*, but that would be a relationship between a smile and the *concept* of contentment (an imposed relationship - concepts don't smile), not between a smile and a contented person (an intrinsic relationship).

If, in a hypothetical culture, bananas were placed in front of contented people, one might say that *a banana is a symbol of contentment*, but it would be weird to say that *a banana is a sign of contentment* because there is no intrinsic link between contentment and bananas (contentment doesn't produce bananas).

So in your first example, I'd call meat with hair a *symbol* unless you read a mystical component into the context. The bananas in your second example are definitely symbols - they represent a wish and are not a by-product (or herald) of happiness.

Comment: Yes, +1 for using the word 'evidence' here. That is exactly right in these cases.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd start from [Peircian Semiotics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiotic_elements_and_classes_of_signs) to pick apart the nuances and make sure that I meant what I meant to mean.

Anyway, I'd stand **sign** in for Peirce's **index**. A *sign* points to some specific instance of something [or *some thing*]. A **symbol** stands in for the idea [and perhaps *idea* could be taken in the Platonic sense to some extent]. The world of symbols is complex: `characters on screen stand in for sounds -> sounds stand in for words -> words stand in for things in the world -> things in the world may be symbols`. Normally signs don't point around in circles.